# appJar python: button press action

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, button, widget

I am trying to get a hand-on experience on **appJar** with **python3** for GUI programming. I am trying to add an action to take place when button is pressed. it works OK but it ends strangely.

Part of the code is below. the function "pressed" is getting called whenever the button is pressed. it works fine. However, when the count reaches 0, the number 0 is not pressed (although, as per the code, the number 0 should be printed on the label named "lb1").
when the button is pressed and the count variable =1, the count variable should get decremented by one, then the label text should be updated with the new count number. then, it checks if the counter =0 and if true, it exits the code.
Now, the form get terminated before updating the label with the new value. with some troubleshooting, I found the label value is only updated upon the termination of the form although the line of code that updates it is executed already.

Anyone can shed some light on this?

```
from appJar import gui
count=10
def pressed(btnName):
    global count
    count-=1
    win.setLabel("lb1","Count= "+ str(count))
    if count==0:
        win.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're seeing is expected behaviour.

When count reaches 0 - the label update is queued to happen, but then the next line of code stops the GUI, this will happen just a few milliseconds later - so the GUI will be gone before there is a chance to update what is being shown on the screen.

If you want to introduce a slight delay, between the label updating and the GUI closing, you could use the `.after()` function.

For example:

```
if count == 0:
    win.after(500, win.stop)
```

This will delay 500 milliseconds before calling the stop function.

---

Alternatively, if you want the GUI to stay open, displaying `Count= 0`, and only close the next time the user presses the button, change your original code to only call `win.stop()` when `count == -1`

---

So, the full code might look like:

```
from appJar import gui 
count=10
def pressed(btnName):
    global count
    count-=1
    win.setLabel("lb1","Count= "+ str(count))
    if count == 0:
        win.after(500, win.stop)

win = gui()
win.addLabel("lb1", "empty")
win.addButton("PRESS", pressed)
win.go()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I used the sleep() before the win.stop() but It didn't work. The label is only updated only upon function exit
I tried your solution. It didn't work as you explained. I used .after() but no matter what value I use, the GUI form quits immediately after the counter reaches zero. Nonetheless, the program ending delays (I can see that from console) but not the GUI. In other words, the GUI form quits immediately but the program keeps running for the _delay_ value configured.
I can conclude that the .after() method adds a delay after the GUI quits, not before.

Comment: Using `sleep()` will pause the GUI thread - preventing any updates to occur. Once the `sleep()` finishes the GUI will exit immediately - so you wouldn't see the label update.

I've updated my original answer to include an example code listing. `.after()` queues the function call in the GUI's event loop, so the GUI will be updated and only after the specified number of milliseconds (in this case 500) will the GUI exit.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the problem. After inspecting the code more closely, I found I didn't use the .after() method accurately. I wrote win.after(200,win.stop())
instead
win.after(200,win.stop)

That's why I didn't work the first time. Now its working successfully. Thank you.